# Multiple headers in get_file_contents not functioning

Tags: php, json, api, file-get-contents

I am trying to pass multiple headers through to a URL (API server) using file_get_contents. The code I have below echos out a HTTP 500 error:

```
$userdetails = http_build_query(
array(
    'userdetails' => '

                        {

                "jobId": null, "collectionOnDelivery": false, "invoice": null,

                "collectionDate": "2014-08-27T09:11:00", "consolidate": false,

                "consignments": [{ "collectionDetails":{

                "contactDetails":{ "contactName":"Mr David Smith" "telephone":"0121 500 2500"

                },

                "address":{

                "organisation":"GeoPost UK Ltd", "property":"",

                "street":"Roebuck Lane", "locality":"Smethwick", "town":"Birmingham", "county":"West Midlands", "postcode":"B66 1BY", "countryCode":"GB",

                }

                },

                "deliveryDetails":{

                "contactDetails":{ "contactName":"Mr David Smith"

                "telephone":"0121 500 2500"

                },

                "notificationDetails":{ "mobile":"07921 123456" "email":"david.smith@acme.com"

                },

                "address":{ "organisation":"ACME Ltd",

                "property":"Miles Industrial Estate", "street":"42 Bridge Road", "locality":"",

                "town":"Birmingham", "county":"West Midlands", "postcode":"B1 1AA", "countryCode":"GB",

                }

                },

                "networkCode":"1^12",

                "numberOfParcels":1,

                "totalWeight":5, "shippingRef1":"Catalogue Batch 1", "shippingRef2":"Invoice 231", "shippingRef3":"", "customsValue":0,

                "deliveryInstructions":"Please deliver to industrial gate A", "parcelDescription":"",

                "liabilityValue":0,

                "liability":false,

                "parcel":[]

                }]

                }



    '

    )
 );




$content = array('http' =>
    array(
         'method'  => 'POST',
         'header'  => "GEOSESSION: ".$geosession,
          "Accept: application/json",
           "Content-Type: application/json",
            'content' => $userdetails

     )
  );

   $context2  = stream_context_create($content);

   $result_userdetails = file_get_contents('https://api.interlinkexpress.com/shipping/shipment', false, $context2);


 echo $result_userdetails;
```

The thing is I have tried/tested the headers on POSTMAN and I am getting a response back however when I pass it through the code above I get the error. I am unsure why this is and was wondering if I am actually passing all three headers across or not? Could someone please clarify whether this is the case or if there is an error?

UPDATE:

I have tried changing the userdetails to the below as someone pointed out it was already in JSON format however the API does not seem to be liking the 'content' => $userdetails now?

```
$userdetails = $userdetails = http_build_query(
array(
    'userdetails' => '

                   {
"job_id": null,
"collectionOnDelivery": false,
"invoice": null,
"collectionDate": "",
"consolidate": false,
"consignment": [{
    "consignmentNumber": null,
    "consignmentRef": null,
    "parcels": [],
    "collectionDetails": {
        "contactDetails": {
            "contactName": "My Contact",
            "telephone": "0121 500 2500"
        },
        "address": {
            "organisation": "GeoPostUK Ltd",
            "countryCode": "GB",
            "postcode": "B66 1BY",
            "street": "Roebuck Lane",
            "locality": "Smethwick",
            "town": "Birmingham",
            "county": "West Midlands"
        }
    },
    "deliveryDetails": {
        "contactDetails": {
            "contactName": "My Contact",
            "telephone": "0121 500 2500"
        },
        "address": {
            "organisation": "GeoPostUK Ltd",
            "countryCode": "GB",
            "postcode": "B66 1BY",
            "street": "Roebuck Lane",
            "locality": "Smethwick",
            "town": "Birmingham",
            "county": "West Midlands"
        },
        "notificationDetails": {
            "email": "my.email@geopostuk.com",
            "mobile": "07921000001"
        }
    },
    "networkCode": "2^12",
    "numberOfParcels": 1,
    "totalWeight": 5,
    "shippingRef1": "My Ref 1",
    "shippingRef2": "My Ref 2",
    "shippingRef3": "My Ref 3",
    "customsValue": null,
    "deliveryInstructions": "Please deliver with neighbour",
    "parcelDescription": "",
    "liabilityValue": null,
    "liability": false
}]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple headers should be connected using CRLF

```
$content = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => "GEOSESSION: " . $geosession . "\r\n" .
                     "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
                     "Content-Type: application/json",
        'content' => $userdetails

    )
);
```

To encode the data properly, first create a PHP containing the data, and then use `json_encode` to format it:

```
$data = array("jobId" => null, "collectionOnDelivery" => false, "invoice" => null,

              "collectionDate" => "2014-08-27T09:11:00", "consolidate" => false,

              "consignments" => array(array( "collectionDetails" =>
                                             array("contactDetails" => array( "contactName" => "Mr David Smith" "telephone" => "0121 500 2500"),
                                                   "address" => array("organisation" => "GeoPost UK Ltd", "property" => "",
                                                                      "street" => "Roebuck Lane", "locality" => "Smethwick", "town" => "Birmingham",
                                                                      "county" => "West Midlands", "postcode" => "B66 1BY", "countryCode" => "GB",)
                                                   ),
                                             "deliveryDetails" => array("contactDetails" => array( "contactName" => "Mr David Smith"
                                                                                                   "telephone" => "0121 500 2500"
                                                                                                   ),
                                                                        "notificationDetails" => array( "mobile" => "07921 123456" "email" => "david.smith@acme.com"),
                                                                        "address" => array( "organisation" => "ACME Ltd",
                                                                                            "property" => "Miles Industrial Estate", "street" => "42 Bridge Road", "locality" => "",
                                                                                            "town" => "Birmingham", "county" => "West Midlands", "postcode" => "B1 1AA", "countryCode" => "GB",)
                                                                        ),
                                             "networkCode" => "1^12",
                                             "numberOfParcels" => 1,
                                             "totalWeight" => 5, "shippingRef1" => "Catalogue Batch 1", "shippingRef2" => "Invoice 231", "shippingRef3" => "", "customsValue" => 0,
                                             "deliveryInstructions" => "Please deliver to industrial gate A", "parcelDescription" => "",
                                             "liabilityValue" => 0,
                                             "liability" => false,
                                             "parcel" => array()
                                             ))
              );
$userdetails = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: A right okay I had similar to that however I missed the \r\n part off. Will try that now

Comment: Im still receiving the same error: Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.interlinkexpress.com/shipping/shipment): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: You specify that the content type is JSON, but you're using `http_build_query` instead of `json_encode`. `http_build_query` produces `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Okay I will try using JSON encode and see what happens

Comment: Someone pointed out to me that the format I have is already in JSON format will it still require to be encoded?

Comment: It's not in JSON format until you call `json_encode`. Before that it's a PHP array.

Comment: Are you sure the API really wants JSON? If it expects input from a form, that usually uses x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: The API does want it in JSON format as I have checked numerous times with the company who's api we are trying to connect it to. Apologies I am relatively new to JSON how would I go about encoding it?

Comment: Oh, now I see, you actually do have a huge string that's in JSON format. But you're putting that in the value of a form field named `userdetails`. What format does the API want the form data itself sent in? It seems unlikely that it wants JSON inside JSON. Either the entire data should be JSON, or the JSON should be inside a url-encoded parameter.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the API documentation?

Comment: Bear with me and I will provide it for you (its rather confusing) also the contents in user detail contains syntax errors so would not work (we have new test data)

Comment: The link is http://www.kitlocker.com/Shipping%20APIs%20Interlink%20Express-1.pdf page 22 is what I am looking at implementing

Comment: Managed to get it working - I removed the $userdetails and just placed the code straight into the content bit

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But I'll post a better way to do it.